# os.path.exists() weird behaviour on python 3.10.6

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

myFile = True
if os.path.exists(myFile):
    print("True exists !!")
```

Do we know why prints "True exists !!" even when there is no file named "True" ?

- Python Version: Python 3.10.6
- OS: Linux Mint 21 Vanessa
- Kernel: 5.15.0-94-generic